# Add empty row with message "No results found"

Tags: slickgrid

When there's no data I want SlickGrid to display a message that states something like "No results found". Any way of doing that? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: Your question is a bit too simple... I mean, how to you pull your data for example? Through AJAX, only JS, or..? What code have you tried? Where do you want to display the message, an alert or a div or in the grid? I pull my data through `$.getJSON()`, I could answer for that, but since I'm not sure what you use... You won't find that in the doc since there's much more then 1 way of pulling data!

Comment: Honestly this is a standard feature of any grid I've tried so far - if no data is returned, regardless of how you load that data, you can show a message in the grid saying that there's no data. I hacked it a bit as per my answer bellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I hacked it a bit like the following (data is loaded via ajax following the example they have at "example6-ajax-loading.html"):

```
loader.onDataLoaded.subscribe(function (e, args) {
 // check if there's any data in the data array
 .... 

 if (!anyData) {
    grid.invalidateAllRows();
    $('.grid-canvas').html('<div>No Data.</div>');
    return;
 }
```

}

Comment: Yes that is something similar I have, use the same <div> as the grid and just replace the grid by an warning message of no data. I am not aware of any special function built in for that purpose